# Select and highlight text in Android WebView

Tags: android, webview, selection, highlighting

I'm developing app for Android smartphones >= 2.1 with WebView.
Webview contains page with text data.

I want to let a user select a text in WebView and then highlight it.
I realized selection, via [emulateShiftHeld()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#emulateShiftHeld%28%29), but it stupid copies selected text into Clipboard.

Can I set JS callback for selection finished event inside page html?
Or, may be, in Java set a WebView's listener for the same?

Thank you

Comment: refer this link 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8503270/tracking-the-selecting-text-in-android-webview/8542992#8542992

Comment: Did you get solution of above issues?

Answer (score 4):

I am using a github project called [BTAndroidWebViewSelection](https://github.com/btate/BTAndroidWebViewSelection) to get web view selections working in 2.2 - 4.0.3. This project uses a javascript interface that gets all touches passed to it. The solution seems to work pretty well. This github project includes the necessary javascript files in the assets folder as well as a test page and a `WebView` that loads the test page and implements all necessary methods to handle the selection.