# How to get text selection of the react-native WebView?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, webview

We are building an news reader APP using React Native.
Each news article are rendered inside a WebView.

We'd like to make user can select some text of the article and highlight it. Just like what can be seen in normal ebook reader Apps. Like this:

[image]

In a normal Desktop web browser. We can use 'mouseup' even and window.getSelection() to do the work. But in ReactNative's WebView. We don't know how to do it.

Please help, thanks.

Comment: see here https://stackoverflow.com/a/12353366/3872374 , and here https://github.com/btate/BTAndroidWebViewSelection

Comment: Thank you, I have read this question before, this is not a solution for React Native. We are trying to avoid mess up with Native Code right now.

Comment: sorry, this one is unrelated

Answer (score 1):

You *can* use `mouseup` event and get content with `window.getSelection()`. The only problem here is that RN part is not aware of this event happening inside webview, however you can propogate this event up to React Native with `window.postMessage` and `onMessage` prop of RN WebView. Alternatively you can use [my tiny wrapper](https://github.com/R1ZZU/react-native-webview-messaging) for communication between ReactNative and WebView